# How to implement Authentication and Authorization Nodejs Azure Functions App with Azure AD

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, authorization

I want to implement the Authentication and Authorization Nodejs Azure Functions service using Azure AD. I was following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad). And I got a [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-nodejs-webapi-azurefunctions) from this article. It looks like they have used expressjs, passportjs but I need only for the Azure functions app.

A sample code would be helpful. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- In your Function app under `authentication` click on `add identity provider`
  [image]
- Now Select the `Microsoft` as `Indentity Provider`

[image]

- Then select `Create new App REgistration` and `Current tenant-Single Tenant` and then click `Add`
  [image]
- Now you can get token from the recently created app registration and then we can use to auth our nodejs function.

[image]